# Sequence of monotonic increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of montonic increasing functions which converges almost everywhere (in Lebesgue measure) to a function $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

> How to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ for any point $x$ where $f$ is continuous (pointwisely)?

I really don't know where to start. This is exam preparation, please reply. Thank you.

Comment: Converges uniformly or pointwise?

Comment: Do you mean that $f_n$ is an increasing sequence of continuous functions?

Comment: @Sir Jective Converges pointwise at those points

Comment: @sranthrop No, I do mean each $f_n$ is monotonic increasing, but the sequence $f_n$ is not an increasing sequence of functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x$. We show that for any neighborhood $U$ of $f(x)$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $f_n(x) \in U$.

Let $U$ be an open interval containing $f(x)$. As $f$ is continuous at $x$, there is a neighborhood $(c,d)$ of $x$ such that $f((c,d)) \subseteq U$. As $\{f_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere, for some $x_0 \in (c,x)$, $f_n(x_0) \rightarrow f(x_0)$, and for some $x_1 \in (x,d)$, $f_n(x_1) \rightarrow f(x_1)$. Fix such an $x_0$ and $x_1$. Then for some $N$, for all $n>N$ $f_n(x_0) \in U$ and $f_n(x_1) \in U$. But then, as the $f_n$ are monotonically increasing and $x_0 < x < x_1$, for all $n>N$ $f_n(x) \in U$.